# Event.StartDateTime: Only date field is displayed

Tags: email-template, event

When I use "Event.StartDateTime" in a HTML email template, only the Date would show up. Is this a Salesforce bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: is the event is all day event?

Comment: Nope, it is not an all day event.